# UDP Socket receive fails in wp7

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7

I am newbie for WP7 and Socket programming. I have gone through msdn sample code [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202864(v=VS.92).aspx#Y4537](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202864%28v=VS.92%29.aspx#Y4537) and tested for use. Send works fine but it couldn't receive, this is the code I have used for receiving udp packet data.

In this my Breakpoint always fails @ `if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)`

```
    public string Receive(int portNumber)
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are receiving over an established socket connection
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);

            // Setup the buffer to receive the data
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset,e.BytesTransferred);
                        response = response.Trim('\0');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                    }
                    _clientDone.Set();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.ToString();
                }

            });

            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
            _socket.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);


            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the specific UDP support in WP7/Silverlight? Either using [UdpSingleSourceMulticastClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpsinglesourcemulticastclient%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [UdpAnySourceMulticastClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpanysourcemulticastclient%28VS.95%29.aspx) depending on your scenario and requirements. Here's an intro article on UDP in Silverlight @ [Working with Multicast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707325%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: :can You plz give any Working Sample for UDP Receive ?

Comment: No. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish there are many Silverlight 4 blog posts out there that explain the finer points of UDP implementation using the 2 classes I've just mentioned.